# S3 to XML Parse to Pandas

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have many XML files sitting in S3 and I'm trying to get them into pandas and from there to MSSQL. In this example I'm using etree to parse the file but honestly I don't care if it's LMXML or any other package. However, I don't think any content is actually getting read from the file. Below is my code, and the error.  I feel like I'm so close, but, it's very possible that I'm not! Cheers

### Code

```
    import boto3
from pprint import pprint
import lxml
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et 
import pandas as pd

client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
result = paginator.paginate(
    Bucket='MYBUCKET',
    Prefix='FOLDER/FOLDER2/')

bucket_object_list = []

for page in result:
    pprint(page)
    if "Contents" in page:
        for key in page["Contents"]:
            keyString = key["Key"]
            pprint(keyString)
            bucket_object_list.append(keyString)

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for file_name in bucket_object_list:
    obj = s3.Object('MYBUCKET', file_name)
    print(obj.get())
    xmldata = obj.get()["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')

parsed_xml = et.parse(xmldata)
dfcols = ['col1','col2', 'col3']
df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

for node in parsed_xml.getroot():
    col1 = node.find('col1')
    col2 = node.find('col2')
    col3 = node.find('col3')
        df_xml = df_xml.append(
        pd.Series([getvalueofnode(col1), getvalueofnode(col2), getvalueofnode(col3)], index=dfcols),
        ignore_index=True)

print(df_xml)
```

### Error

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xmlnightmare.py", line 31, in <module>
    parsed_xml = et.parse(xmldata)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 647, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'<?xml version="1.0"?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .....
>   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'

`ElementTree.parse()` expects location of the XML document in the argument. If you have the content of the XML document, as indicated by the error message above, you should have used `ElementTree.fromstring()` instead :

```
....
parsed_xml = et.fromstring(xmldata)
dfcols = ['col1','col2', 'col3']
....
```

Comment: Hmm still no dice..

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s3test1.py", line 37, in <module>
    for node in parsed_xml.getroot():
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'

Comment: @DataDog did you ever solve this?  i am facing same issue.

Comment: I did, a long long time ago.  Did you start a question?